# Metaquoting patterns in a variable list

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, metacharacters

I have a list of patterns I want to look for in a string. These patterns are numerous and contain numerous metacharacters that I want to just match literally. So this is the perfect application for metaquoting with `\Q..\E`. The complication is that I need to join the variable list of patterns into a regular expression.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# sample string to represent my problem
    my $string = "{{a|!}} Abra\n{{b|!!}} {{b}} Hocus {{s|?}} Kedabra\n{{b|+?}} {{b|??}} Pocus\n {{s|?}}Alakazam\n";

# sample patterns to look for    
my @patterns = qw({{a|!}} {{s|?}} {{s|+?}} {{b|?}});
# since these patterns can be anything, I join the resulting array into a variable-length regex
my $regex = join("|",@patterns);

my @matched = $string =~ /$regex(\s\w+\s)/; # Error in matching regex due to unquoted metacharacters
print join("", @matched); # intended result: Hocus\n Pocus\n
```

When I attempt to introduce metaquoting into the joining operation, they appear to have no effect.

```
# quote all patterns so that they match literally, but make sure the alternating metacharacter works as intended
my $qmregex = "\Q".join("\E|\Q", @patterns)."\E";

my @matched = $string =~ /$qmregex(\s\w+\s)/; # The same error
```

For some reason the metaquoting has no effect when it is included in the string I use as the regular expression. For me, they only work when they are added directly to a regex as in `/\Q$anexpression\E/` but as far as I can tell this isn't an option for me. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your expected result, as `Abra` and `Kedabra` are the only strings preceded by any of the patterns.

To solve your problem you must escape each component of the regex separately as `\Q` and `\E` affect only the value of the string in which they appear, so `"\Q"` and `"\E"` are just the null string `""` and `"\E|\Q"` is just `"|"`. You could write

```
my $qmregex = join '|', map "\Q$_\E", @patterns;
```

but it is simpler to call the `quotemeta` function.

You must also enclose the list in parentheses `(?:...)` to isolate the alternation, and apply the `/g` modifier to the regex match to find all ocurrences within the string.

Try

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "{{a|!}} Abra\n{{b|!!}} {{b}} Hocus {{s|?}} Kedabra\n{{b|+?}} {{b|??}} Pocus\n {{s|?}}Alakazam\n";

my @patterns = qw(  {{a|!}} {{s|?}} {{s|+?}} {{b|?}}  );

my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @patterns;
my @matched = $string =~ /(?:$regex)(\s\w+\s)/g;
print @matched;
```

**output**

```
 Abra
 Kedabra
```